# Checking rows and columns in datagridview if has no changes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to check in Datagridview if there is no changes then prompt the user of no changes in my datagridview. I want to do this in my Update button to check first if there is no changes prompt msgbox then exit sub. how to do that? Lets say data from database already loaded to datagridview.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

'this line is what I want for checking will happen if there is no changes in data happens in datagridview

        Dim row, id, dgvUnits As Integer
        Dim dgvYearLevel, dgvSemester, dgvCNo, dgvCDescription As String

        'Declared this variable to get value event click on dgv
        row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        id = DataGridView1(6, row).Value
        dgvYearLevel = DataGridView1(1, row).Value
        dgvSemester = DataGridView1(2, row).Value
        dgvCNo = DataGridView1(3, row).Value
        dgvCDescription = DataGridView1(4, row).Value
        dgvUnits = DataGridView1(5, row).Value

        Try
            con.Open()

            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "UPDATE tblcurriculumcourses SET YearLevel='" & dgvYearLevel & "', Semester='" & dgvSemester & "', CourseNo='" & dgvCNo & "', CourseDes='" & dgvCDescription & "', Units='" & dgvUnits & "' where PrimaryDummy='" & id & "'"
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            MsgBox("Data Has Been Successfully Update!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error when updating data")
        End Try
```

Comment: a) Turn on Option Strict b) Always use SQL Parameters rather than concat little bits of string to make SQL c) If you use a datasource it will tell you if there are changes d) if you hold onto your adapter it will update for you

Comment: Dont know how to do that, Im just a beginner student.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a legitimate answer, but I got an idea. Maybe, you can dim one of the rows in the DataGridView as an array or string, and later, on the button, you can do something like

```
If DataGridView1(1, row).Value = TheArrayOrString Then
 'This is what you want it to do. Example:
   MsgBox("Your table is the same!")
```

Maybe, try something like that, also, you'd have to select all the rows for the DataGridView! What it is doing is once you make all the rows in a DataGridView an ArrayList, you can test if it hasn't changed or not. So the 'If DataGridView1(1, row).Valie = TheArrayOrString' is testing if the DataGridView1 table has had the same contents over a period of time. The 'MsgBox("Your table is the same!")' is self explantory. Hope this helps spread your imagination! Have fun! :)